# Изменяются размеры body при изменении right/left в мобильной верссии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт http://kolik29.ru/. При клике на Профиль, Резюме, Портфолио или Контакты две "половинки" страницы разъезжаются в разные стороны. В мобильной же версии блоки разъезжаются криво - как будто изменяется высота и ширина всей страницы.

Нижний блок смещается влево с помощью функции animate() из Jquery путем изменения свойства right.

```
$('.﻿half-screen.right').animate({
        right: slide_to
    }, 500);﻿﻿
```

Comment: Учите адаптивную верстку

Answer (score 0):

Не используй top, left, right, bottom для анимаций, ибо отрабатывает CPU. Используй transform: translate(); ибо обрабатывается через GPU. Уточни в каком браузере или на каком устройстве конкретно проблема.